# INSERT INTO Too few parameters

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table named **tb_tools**, with the following fields:

- **TOOL_ID** (Short text) [key_field]
- DESCRIPTION (Short text)
- RACK (Short Text)
- COLUMN (Number)
- COMMENTS (Long text)

In a form called frm_insertion i have a button with a click event

```
Private Sub btn_add_Click()
    Dim part_temp As String
    Dim tempNum As Integer
    Dim tempStr As String

    tempNum = 12
    tempStr = "test"

    tool_temp = Nz(DLookup("[TOOL_ID]", "tb_tools", "[TOOL_ID]='" & [box_dien] & "'"), "-1")

    If StrComp(tool_temp, "-1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [tb_dies] ([TOOL_ID], [DESCRIPTION], [RACK], [COLUMN], [COMMENTS]) " _
            & "VALUES (" & tool_temp & "," & tempStr & "," & tempStr & "," & tempNum & "," & tempStr & ")"
    End If
End Sub
```

I get the error "Too few parameters. Expected 1" in the INSERT INTO line. I've checked the field names. In fact, i copied and pasted them into the code directly from the table.

I've also used the code provided here:
http://forums.devarticles.com/microsoft-access-development-49/check-if-a-field-exists-in-a-table-using-vba-58559.html
To check if the fields are available

Comment: build your SQL string into a string then do `currentdb.execute(ssql)`.  That way you can `debug.print SQL` before executing it or `msgbox(sSQL)`.  My guess is one of your variable values is blank, or has special characters that need to be handled.  By showing the SQL the code generates, we can back into what the problem is.  Consider if your values looks like.... doesn't seem like you've got apostrophe's around your string values which would cause issue as well..  Consider using paramaterized queries to avoid the headache and avoid SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL string contains:

```
INSERT INTO [tb_dies] ([TOOL_ID], [DESCRIPTION], [RACK], [COLUMN], [COMMENTS]) 
VALUES (-1,temp,temp,12,temp,temp)
```

Which isn't valid SQL - right now the database server will consider those occurrences of `temp` to be a variable or column name; the `temp` probably needs to be in single apostrophes (meaning "a string"), like this:

```
INSERT INTO [tb_dies] ([TOOL_ID], [DESCRIPTION], [RACK], [COLUMN], [COMMENTS]) 
VALUES (-1,'temp','temp',12,'temp','temp')
```

Hence you probably want your VB to be:

```
tempStr = "'test'"
```

PS; being MS Access, there's a chance that standard SQL wont work, and that single apostrophes aren't used for strings. If it's double quotes `"` to denote a string in access, you'll be looking at VBlike:

```
tempStr = """test"""
```

The commenters make valid points; you shouldn't use string concatenation to build SQL queries.. It's worth having a read through http://bobby-tables.com right now to get some background info on why it's bad, and then you'll be better equipped to embark down a path of software development that avoids writing software susceptible to this particular (and common) form of hacking

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I added """ & tool_temp & """ (two pairs of double quotes) for each parameter that is a string

Comment: Open to SQL injection! if variables aren't sanitized!

Comment: I agree with @xQbert, although I've never known of SQL injection being used on an Access database.  If you're worrying about injection attacks you should be thinking about using something other than Access.

Answer (score 2):

This may be easier to follow when using parameters in a query.

```
Private Sub btn_add_Click()

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS lToolID LONG, DescText TEXT (255), RackText TEXT (255), " & _
        "ColumnNum LONG, CommentText LONGTEXT; " & _
        "INSERT INTO tb_dies (TOOL_ID, DESCRIPTION, RACK, COLUMN, COMMENTS) " & _
        "VALUES (lToolID, DescText, RackText, ColumnNum, CommentText)")

    With qdf
        .Parameters("lToolID") = 1
        .Parameters("DescText") = "Some Text"
        .Parameters("RackText") = "Some Rack Text"
        .Parameters("ColumnNum") = 5
        .Parameters("CommentText") = "Some really long comments"
        .Execute
    End With

    Set qdf = Nothing

End Sub
```

The SQL reads as:

```
PARAMETERS  lToolID LONG
            , DescText TEXT (255)
            , RackText TEXT (255)
            , ColumnNum LONG
            , CommentText LONGTEXT; 
INSERT INTO tb_dies (TOOL_ID, DESCRIPTION, RACK, COLUMN, COMMENTS) 
VALUES      (lToolID, DescText, RackText, ColumnNum, CommentText);
```